# Open Eclipse in elevated privileges

Tags: php, eclipse

I'm trying to run a php site using eclipse pdt. I set it up to copy the files to `var/www/`. It gives no error but only opens `localhost/myProjName` in its browser. So I'm assuming I need to give eclipse some privileges to copy files there. How do I do this?

I dont even know where eclipse is located, I open it via `Dash Home`.

Comment: Perhaps try start Eclipse with elevated privileges. Run `gksudo eclipse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can run eclipse (or any program for that matter) as root by pressing Alt-F2 then entering gksu eclipse (or gksudo)
However I wouldn't recommend this as running a program as run is never a good idea.

A better solution would be to open a terminal and make the directory /var/www/myProjName and then giving yourself permission to write to it:

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/myProjName

sudo chown yourusername myProjName
```

that should hopefully work for you